# Jewish Babylonian Aramaic - Flashcards

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, words, talmud-bavli, aramaic

Does anyone know if vocabulary flashcards are available for students of the Aramaic of the Bavli?

Comment: You can purchase my app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.studioussoftware.aramaicflashcards&hl=en&) :-)

Comment: @robev is there an iOS version?

Comment: @YaakovPinchas I would have developed one but they charge to put in the app store so not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access some on chinuch.org [here](http://www.chinuch.org/item_detail/300-Gemara-Vocabulary-Words-and-Flashcards)

It writes there:

> Three hundred commonly found Gemara words in list form and the same words enlarged as flashcards. Both forms make great classroom resources. The list serves as a handy reference when learning or reviewing the Gemara and the flashcards can be used for review games such as matching or memory.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/) as a flashcard application and it has a very rich set of gemara and Aramaic flashcard "study sets" as they call them. See for instance the following search results

- [Gemara vocabulary](https://quizlet.com/search?query=gemara-vocabulary&type=sets)
- [Aramaic](https://quizlet.com/search?query=aramaic&type=sets)
- [Gemara](https://quizlet.com/search?query=gemara&type=sets)

You can use the reviews to guide your selection.